# The spoak laugh generator

Tags: code-golf

## The spoak laugh

For those who don't know, in Brazil some people laugh on chats like this: aposkpaoskaposkaposkpaokspaoskpaoksa.

So here is the challenge: To make a program that generate this laugh in a natural way.

## How to produce this laugh programatticaly?

When you laugh like this, you use one hand on the `(a, s)` part of the keyboard and the other on the `(k, o, p)`  part, randomly hitting the keys on both parts, alterning keys and parts.

I will put some laughs here for you to analise.

- apsokaposkaposkaposkaposkaposkaposkaposkpaoskaposkpaoskaposkapsokaposkaposk
- paoskpaoksaposkaposkaposkaposkaopskaopskaopskpaoskpaoksapokspaoskapsokapsok
- aposkaposkpaoskpaoskaposkpaokspoakspaoksopaksopaskpaoskaopskpaoskapsokpasok
- paoskpaoskaposkaposkapsokaposkaposkapsokaspokaspoksaposakposakaposkaspokaso
- paoskpasokaspokapsokaspokaposkapsokaposkaspokaposkaspoksapaoskpasoksaopksao

You have to study this pattern and produce it on your code.

## What makes a valid spoak laugh?

- In the spoak laugh, a letter ALMOST NEVER repeat twice in a row. So this is mandatory.
- Spliting you string on the k, for example, in this javasript: `generated_string.split('k')` has to produce a list of various substring **ranging from 1 to 6 of length** (more on this later) and with **distance of same letter of minimum 3**. Example: `['spaos', 'asopa']`. In both cases the first letter repeats on the substring, but appears with distance of 3 from the repetition..
- There is no restriction to what character should be first or last in each laugh.

## Order of the substrings:

On a human written spoak laugh of 521 characters, this stats were observed:

`Counter({'apos': 30, 'paos': 20, 'apso': 11, 'sapo': 9, 'paso': 6, 'saposa': 6,
'psao': 4, 'sapoa': 3, 'aspo': 2, 'sopsa': 2, 'saop': 1, 'spo': 1, 'opas': 1, 'p
oas': 1, 'sapoas': 1, 'aops': 1, 'sa': 1, 'aspos': 1})`

We noticed that:

- the top 4 are apos = 30, paos = 20, apso = 11 and sapo = 9
- ...followed by paso and saposa both with 6

This means that when breaking the substrings the most occurrences are: **apos and paos** on 1st and 2nd, followed by **paso, sapo, apso and saposa** in any order, then any other combination, following the other rules.

## Number of characters of each substring

The substrings produced should respect this proportion on a 500 characters spoak laugh:

- 1 char = at least 1%
- 2 char = at least 1%
- 3 char = at least 6%
- 4 char = at least 70%
- 5 char = at least 6%
- 6 char = at least 1%

## Validate you laugh on-line.

- Enter http://www.filipeteixeira.com.br/spoak_validator to validate your generated laugh.
- Submit 10 laughs of 500 length each, separated with a semicolon (;).
- If you laughs are valid, post you code and the generated link here.

## But is this the best way to produce a paoskpaoskaposkpasokaposk laugh?

There would be other ways to produce it, but with rapid observation of pattern and statistics, we will stick to these heuristics.

## Who wins?

Shortest code wins.

Have fun, paoskpaoskpoaskpaoskpsao :D

Comment: aposkpaoskaposkaposkpaokspaoskpaoksa what a fun question :D

Comment: Your validity conditions are too subjective for code golf.

Comment: [Relevant](http://iruntheinternet.com/lulzdump/images/gifs/mantis-lol-lololol-keyboard-typing-1327253876r.gif?id=507).

Comment: xnor, I don't know what you mean with too broad. Could it be opened again if I post a program to validate the answers? or if I change it to popularity contest.

Comment: Yes, precise validation conditions would make OK. I'd suggest that over popularity contest.

Comment: xnor, check it now

Comment: The requirement that splitting on ks should give substrings of length 1 to 5 directly contradicts the requirement that at least 1% of those substrings should be of length 6. And the bit about statistics is a bit vague on what "*similar statistics*" means.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to edit "1 to 5" to "1 to 6" before. I think I was pretty clear about statistics. The number of occurrence of substrings should follow: 
**apos, paos, then [paso, sapo, apso and saposa] in any order then the others**

Comment: When you say that a letter almost never appears consecutive to itself and that it's mandatory for us to replicate this, does that mean it should _never_ happen or that it can but the probability of it happening should be small? If the latter is the case, how small is small?

Comment: The probability is so small that we assume it will never happen. Write aposkpaoskpaosk on you keyboard and check if it happens. It almost never happen, so if we replicate with no repeating it should mimic the laugh with 99,99999999999999% accuracy.